# Image Scaling on ImageView Resource vs. SD Card saved Image

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an Listview with ImageView rows like this (ListView Element):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivThumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDetailsArtist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivThumbnail"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivThumbnail"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:text="placeholder"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

in my ListView ArrayAdapter on getView Method I have following (shortened):

```
// Check if ThumbnailFile exists
File fThumbnail = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/folder/"), elements.get(position)
                .getThumbnailFileName());

if (fThumbnail.exists()) {
    ivThumbnail.setImageURI(Uri.parse(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/folder/")
            + elements.get(position).getThumbnailFileName()));
} else {
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.raw.no_thumbnail);   
    ivThumbnail.setImageResource(R.raw.no_thumbnail);
}
```

**The Problem:**
The *no_thumbnail.png* in *res/raw* (also tested in res/drawable and so on) has same size as the Thumbnails from getThumbnailFileName(). But in the ImageView they are displayed bigger as the Thumbnails.
For testing purpose I had put the *no_thumbnail.png* onto SD Card, where it scaled ok like the other thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

in first you are calling `getThumbnailFileName()` so it's getting the pre-scaled image from source, but in the else statement you are calling the image from source, and then it's scaled based on your `ImageView`, so modifying your call to `getFileName()` instead of `getThumbnailFileName()` should help

Comment: Hi, the Method `getThumbnailFilename()` returns an String like "thumb123.png" or "thumb532.png" so I dont understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: that method returns a string which points to a pre-scaled image, i mean dont use that, use the normal method to get file name, getFileName()